# carrierwave をインストール後、rails g uploader Pictureで「Could not find generator 'uploader'」

Tags: ruby-on-rails

解決しました。コメント頂いたようにcarrierwave がインストールされていないことが分かりました。 (>gem listで確認するのを忘れていました。Gemfileから一度 gem 'carrierwave'を削除してsave。Gemfileにgem 'carrierwave'を追加しインストール。rails g uploader Pictureできました。)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------carrierwave をインストール後、>rails g uploader Pictureで次のメッセージが出ます。
「Could not find generator 'uploader''. Maybe you meant 'model', 'jbuilder' or 'helper'. Run `rails generate --help` for more options.」

「>rails generate --help」で以下のメッセージが出ます。
何をchooseしてどうTypeしたらいいでしょうか？　宜しくお願いします。
(Windows10 Home / ruby 2.4.4 / rails 5.1.6)

```
>rails generate --help
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
 -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
 -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
 -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
 -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
 -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
 assets
 channel
 controller
 generator
 helper
 integration_test
 jbuilder
 job
 mailer
 migration
 model
 resource
 scaffold
 scaffold_controller
 system_test
 task

Coffee:
 coffee:assets

Js:
 js:assets

TestUnit:
 test_unit:generator
 test_unit:plugin
```

Comment: インストールされてないように見えます。インストールしたときの操作の過程と出力を質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: 解決しました！　有難うございました！